# Binary strings between cASP and .Net - why are they different?

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic, binary

I'm trying to pass a binary string (which represents a file) from classic ASP (vbscript) to a .Net method.  This is of course, very simple indeed.  Testing with a simple txt file, we find that the data can be reliably passed to .Net and worked with.

However, as soon as we get to files which include chars in the unicode range, we see that they are routinely converted to different characters and therefore the file is corrupted.  For example:

```
3Ü£ÜkÜGÝ

becomes

ýÿýÿýÿýÿ
```

So I created a couple of methods, one to write out the hex of the string within the .Net world (passed from vb), and the other to write out the hex in the vb world (the source).  here are the results (using the above example text)?

```
What .Net THINKS we sent it:
fd ff fd ff fd ff fd ff 0d 0a 0d 0a 62 65 63 6f 6d 65 73 0d 0a 0d 0a fd ff fd ff fd ff fd ff 00 
What we REALLY sent it:
33 DC A3 DC 6B DC 47 DD 0D 0A 0D 0A 62 65 63 6F 6D 65 73 0D 0A 0D 0A FD FF FD FF FD FF FD FF 00
```

We can see the word "becomes" has been carried across perfectly (ascii chars) as have the final characters.  But the initial characters (3Ü£ÜkÜGÝ) were converted to:

```
fd ff fd ff fd ff fd ff
```

Or the string:

```
ýÿýÿýÿýÿ
```

What is going on here? Both languages support unicode, is there some odd marshalling of the string happening?  Why these particular characters?  Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

If I take **3Ü** in a file and write that out as binary string data in vbscript we get **í°³**. So what's going on there?  I can understand that we now have 3 characters as the first is single byte and the second is double byte.  But why isn't it **3°³** (or something similar), why is **3** converted to **í** etc?  How can I get my original data from this string?  Of course if I say it's encoded to ASCII, I'll get old **?** **3f** character.  I'm obviously missing a fundamental understanding here.

Comment: What are you using to send the text from classic ASP to .NET?

Comment: It's just a method call on a .net instance from classic asp using com interop.

Comment: Are you using the same code pages between the two apps?

Comment: Paul - yup i've set 65001 on the asp script codepage attribute and use 65001 when requesting the encoding to use in .Net. It's a very odd issue, and demonstrates that there's something I don't yet understand about the binary string in vbs.

Comment: Please post the com interop call and definition.  Its likely an issue with that.  You might need to set the `MarshalAsAttribute` attribute to the specific `UnmanagedType` as described on [Default Marshaling for Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Ah interesting, i've tried a few options on MarshalAsAttribute and set to be a ref parameter (clutching at straws with that).  But it doesn't seem to make any difference to the bytes retrieved.  Have you any suggestion on what enum I should use for a VBS binary string?